# Angular 8: HammerJs swipeRight and swipeLeft not working inside overflow:auto

Tags: angular, typescript, hammer.js

I'm making an application that run on a mobile phone. I would like to be able to use the swipe events inside a scrollable container. Right now, if I use `(swipeRight)=""` or `(swipeLeft)=""` the events works fine but I'm enable to scroll anymore inside the container.

I've tried using a gesture config for Hammerjs but it only works vertically, like this:

```
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    overrides = <any> {
        'pinch': { enable: false },
        'rotate': { enable: false }
    }
}

providers: [
    {
        provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
        useClass: MyHammerConfig
    }
],
```

Is there a way to be able to trigger both event `(swipeRight)` and `(swipeLeft)` while inside a working scrollable container?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 overrides = <any> {
        'swipe': {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL,velocity: 0.1},
        'pinch': { enable: false },
        'rotate': { enable: false }
    }
```